# php/mysql: credit card validation isn't working

Tags: php, html

I tried to make this program that takes a credit card number and checks if it it valid or not and let the user know about it but in my program, i dont get echo message at all on clicking submit

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $number=$_POST['cc'];
    $total=0;
    $i=1;
    $last4= substr($number,-4,4);
    $number=$str_split($number);
    $number=array_reverse($number);
    foreach($number as $digit){
        if(i%2==0){
            $digit*=2;
            if($digit>9){
                $digit -=9;
            }
        }
        $total += $digit;
        $i++;
    }
    if($total%10==0){
        echo "Your credit card number ending in ".$last4." is valid";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Your credit card number ending in ".$last4." is invalid";
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Credit Card Number</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="cards.php">
    <input type="text" name="cc">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Specify method in form tag such as method='post' as you are catching post parameters in PHP.

Comment: @NikunjSardhara now i am getting Notice: Undefined variable: str_split in C:\xamppp\htdocs\cpu5001\cards.php on line 8

Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\xamppp\htdocs\cpu5001\cards.php on line 8

Comment: I'm curious; is this live? if so, under SSL? this looks very dangerous

Comment: $str_split is wrong, it should be str_split.

Comment: @Fred-ii- lol no i just need to do this for my assignment.. Creating credit validation forms.

Comment: I had to ask ;-) you wouldn't believe the type of stunts that some try to do *lol*

Comment: @NikunjSardhara now it says Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i' in C:\xamppp\htdocs\cpu5001\cards.php on line 11 :/

Comment: @Fred-ii- hehe yea dont worry i am a beginner in programming so cant do anything lol

Comment: Posting your assignment problems is not any problem but do upvote if someone helps you.

Comment: ah wait i think its cos i didnt put the dollar sign

Comment: Edit: ^ yep --- undefined constant i is this `if(i%2==0)` missed the `$` - so `if($i%2==0)` ;-)

Comment: yea one of u can post the answer so i can upvote it

Comment: I didn't delete it. Post again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Let's go over this, one step at a time.*

Firstly, the following condition never gets met/satisfied, since you're using a POST array against a form that does not (specifically) contain a "post" method in it `<form action="cards.php">`.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
// ...
}
```

Since forms default to a "GET" method when "POST" was not implied, it needs to be included.

```
<form action="cards.php" method="post">
```

Next, we have the following error (pulled from and stated in comments):

> *"Notice: Undefined variable: str_split"*

[`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) should have been declared as a [function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php), rather than a [variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php).

```
$number=$str_split($number);
        ^ $ is a variable character
```

It needs to be removed:

```
$number= str_split($number);
```

And then we have the following error (also pulled from and stated in comments):

> *Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i'"*

That was caused by the missing `$` for the "i" in `if(i%2==0)` and is first declared in `$i=1;`.

It looked for a [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) of that name, and since it did not find one, it threw you that error.

Therefore, it should read as:

```
if($i%2==0)
```

Comment: thanks btw i was having another problem i hope u can help me with? I can't post it here cos i have to wait for 90 mins but i really need my answer :/

Comment: now the validation is working but when i try to enter the card number into my phpmyadmin database, it either shows me 0 or array

Comment: @DavidAdam You're welcome David. Fire away, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: $my_query="INSERT INTO `card`(`No`, `Username`, `CreditCard`, `ExpirationDate`, `CardHolderName`, `Country`) VALUES (NULL,'$ids','$number','$expiray','$Cardholder','$country')"; this is what i put to add it to my database.. I get a notice saying Array to string conversion in C:\xamppp\htdocs\cpu5001\cards.php on line 38

Comment: @DavidAdam Without seeing full code, there isn't much I can do. Check for errors with error reporting and also on the query itself. Since you're dealing with an array, then something isn't right somewhere, and/or isn't treated as an array. Seeing this `$expiray` suggests a spelling mistake; `$expiry` maybe? You may to wait and post another question. Make sure that the db column types are correct and the lengths are long enough, best I can do for you David.

Comment: is there any other way i can contact u? cos this page isn't letting me ask questions anymore. I just need help with this one issue.